# Consider the following simultaneous equations in $x$ and $y$...where $a$ is a real constant: $x+y+axy=a$,$x-2y-xy^2$

Tags: quadratics, systems-of-equations

Consider the following simultaneous equations in $x$ and $y$:
$$x+y+axy=a$$ $$x-2y-xy^2=0$$
where $a$ is a real constant. Show that these equations admit real solutions in $x$ and $y$.
I could not approach the problem.I have no idea how to solve these kind of problems. Please help!

[N.B.-I am not sure of the tag,please feel free to recommend]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Eliminating one of the two unknowns, say $y$ we can form a Cubic equation in $x$

Using [Complex conjugate root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem) theorem,

an odd degree equation with real coefficients has an odd number of (at least one) real root(s)

From the first equation given, if $x$ is real so will be $y$ and vice versa

Comment: No...tried to do that...but this does not happen easily. Not atleast with simple manipulations.

Comment: @Hawk, I think we don't have to find the actual real values. This explanation  should be sufficient

Comment: But, I have to reach a point where the equation is of a single variable...but I cannot reach it.

Comment: @Hawk, why don't you put, $$y=\frac{a-x}{1+ay}$$ (from the first equation)  in the second?

Comment: Did you mean, $x=\dfrac{a-y}{1+ay}$?

Comment: @Hawk, you can eliminate of $x$ or $y$ . But eliminating $x$ is easier, so your option is better

Comment: Yes, I've done it! Thank you!